# fseek(f,0,2); How does this work without SEEK_CUR / SEEK_SET or SEEK_END?

Tags: c, file, fseek

Aren't we supposed to use `SEEK_CUR` / `SEEK_SET` or `SEEK_END` for `whence`? How does it work with just a fixed value?

Answer (score 9):

`SEEK_SET`/`SEEK_CUR`/`SEEK_END` are 0/1/2 respectively, you can use the number or definition.

See definitions here: http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4/newsrc/sys/unistd.h.html

```
/* whence values for lseek(2) */
#define SEEK_SET    0   /* set file offset to offset */
#define SEEK_CUR    1   /* set file offset to current plus offset */
#define SEEK_END    2   /* set file offset to EOF plus offset */
```

Of course, it is bad practice to directly use these numbers as it may change in future implementations (not likely though)

Answer (score 2):

Because SEEK_XXX are macros and have a certain value, in this case, SEEK_END is equal to 2, so it's the same fseek(f,0,SEEK_END) that fseek(f,0,2), but you should use always the macros. You can see this values for example in the notes of http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html (at the end).

Answer (score 2):

Look into your `stdio.h`:

```
#define SEEK_END    2   /* Seek from end of file.  */
```

So after preprocessing your `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END)` becames `fseek(f, 0, 2)` and compiler will see `2` instead of meaningful name. As result we can avoid this name at all and put numerical value right now.

Answer (score 2):

In `stdio.h`,

```
#ifndef SEEK_SET
#define SEEK_SET    0   /* set file offset to offset */
#endif
#ifndef SEEK_CUR
#define SEEK_CUR    1   /* set file offset to current plus offset */
#endif
#ifndef SEEK_END
#define SEEK_END    2   /* set file offset to EOF plus offset */
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

fseek() takes three parameters.

First one is the FILE * it will seek

Second is the int Record size, the value, it is expected to hop in one jump. Notice, it can be a negative value as well.

Third parameter is the offset value from where this hopping is to be done. There are three possible values for it 0,1 and 2.
0 represents beginning of the file
1 represents current location
And, 2 represents the end of file.

The SEEK_END, SEEK_CUR or,the SEEK_SET are merely the Macro Expansions with values of 2,1 and 0 respectively. So when a user uses these macro Expansions rather that using the real values underneath, the pre-processors replaces every such usage with its respective value and compilation goes on as usual.

Comment: The C11  says `SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END, SEEK_SET` are distinct values.  It does not _specify_ them as 0,1,2.

Comment: @chux, yes, they are distinct. Thats why they are three. Its an operational parameter, precisely function bound.

Comment: This answers says "There are three possible values for it 0,1 and 2".  My comment points out that is not supported by the C spec.  Although common, a compliant compiler could use other distinct values or a different order.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I am calling it function bound. Whoever defines this function (compiler/library vendor), the fate of these values hang in their hands. ;)